# What is causing Ubuntu 18.10 to stop boot process at backlit black screen after latest OS updates?

Tags: 14.04, kernel, updates, video, 18.10

Did latest OS updates on 4 Feb 2019 on HP Elitebook 2530P.  Updates required restart.  System restarted, but hung with backlit black screen.  Could only get it to work by interrupting boot and reverting to Kernel 4.10.0-13-generic.  Stalls every time you try to boot normally.  Was also able to get it to boot to Kernel 4.10.0-14-generic by putting i915.modeset=0 in grub.  However graphic performance was poor.

Comment: Are your details correct?  You reverted to a EOL 17.04 kernel?  (kernel 4.10 is from Ubuntu 17.04 & well past EOL, no meltdown/spectre etc patches. 4.18 was the kernel used in 18.10)

Comment: Possible known bug: LP #[1814555](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1814555) that is currently in process of being fixed.

Comment: What video card/chip? If nVidia, did you install directly from nVidia or use the Ubuntu repository. If nVidia .run file, you in effect have to reinstall with every kernel update.

Comment: This is a known problem with the -14 kernel. Boot using the -13 kernel until they come out with an updated kernel.

Comment: Note that the Kernel references were pulled from the recovery screen. Does sound like a bug that Ubuntu is fixing. The card is an Intel Graphics Media Accelerator (GMA) 4500MHD and I used Ubuntu repository.

Comment: OK, so maybe I didn't have my glasses on?!  Running Linux kernel 4.18.0-13-generic